# Updating multiple instances of the same source?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml-rpc, updating

I am setting up a new project (`a PHP CMS`) that will be used on `several websites` and will most likely be hosted on the same server, but can be hosted on a different server too. The `source` of the CMS `will be the same for all of these websites`, apart of that they will have their own datatabase credentials of course. So apart of a config file the source will always be identical.

Now my question is, what is the best way to keep all the instances of the CMS updated at the same time? `That I fix a bug on the 'master' version of the CMS and can somehow push that fix to all other instances?`

I've already implemented a way to update the database through `CodeIgniter migrations`, now I only have to figure out how to update all of the scripts/files automaticly in one go.

I have had an internship 3 years ago at a company that needed the same and I remember that they used `XML-RPC` to update all of the versions of their source; but reading the codeigniter docs it seems like `XML-RPC` shouldn't be used in that way. (If I'm not mistaken)

Is it maybe a good practice to do this in git somehow? Setting up a repo for all of the websites? I have no idea. Can someone explain the best practice to me?

Comment: A few years ago we used `ansible` to not only keep the versions up to date as to deploy new developed websites to our servers. We had more than 20 servers at the time and ansible was a huge tools to help us out and save us time. 
I know you can also do this with `Kubernetes`

Comment: will you be in control of whatever server the CMS runs on? If so, the easiest way would be just to keep everything in version control and when a new version is available for the master branch, just deploy it on the customer's servers. You may do it in a number of ways as long as all servers can pull from the repo

Comment: a few keywords - git/svn + jenkins - but you need to investigate for your own

Comment: @JavierLarroulet I will be in control yes, I will look into this as an option. Thank you!

Comment: @digo santo I will look into ansible and kubernetes, thank you!

Comment: @sintakonte ah Jenkins, I do have a little experience with that (have used it at work) - I will look into that too. Thank you!